# How to make a global variable in sveltekit?

Tags: sveltekit

I need a global variable to store the current user state and token. But I can't understand how this is done in the latest version of SvelteKit. How can I make it visible from all components of the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend returning that from a [`load` function in the top-level `+layout.js`/`ts`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#layout-data). Then it will be part of every page `data` and also via the [`page` store](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#public-types-page) data, so you could use something like `$page.data.user` in any component.

Comment: Could you please spell it out in a more detail, I'm a little confused about it. I have an Auth component in order to produce SignUp SignIn. I want to use a separate api service for the backend side. Here I am sending a request to the server in the component Auth , where do I save the data about user I get from the server so I can access it from the rest of the components? I have use JWT tokens